# Flutter Icons widgets no preview in vscode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Below shows the recommended icons however doesn't show the preview in the vscode. This just happened recently.

[image: Unable to find the icon]

Comment: try to reinstall flutter and dart extension

Comment: Maybe You have lost your internet connection or you have slow internet.

Comment: Also happened to me today when I updated flutter :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a regression in VS Code:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128315
- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/119786

I haven't been able to find a workaround will need to wait for a fix. I would recommend putting 's on those issues.

Answer (score -1):

Hi its been months now since this issue and its already been fixed by the latest update of vscode on my machine.

```
Version: 1.60.0 (Universal)
Commit: e7d7e9a9348e6a8cc8c03f877d39cb72e5dfb1ff
Date: 2021-09-01T10:54:53.442Z
Electron: 13.1.8
Chrome: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 20.6.0
```

I'm using macbook-pro. I suggest you guys to update your vscode to the latest version for the fix.

Comment: I am using the latest version: 1.67.2 (Universal), but still face the same issue on my Mac M1 17inches

Answer (score -2):

Just restart your `vs-code` then go to the terminal and run the command `flutter pub get`.